# How to run all TestNG test in a package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, run-configuration

I have a growing number of TestNG based unit test in my eclipse project. To make sure alle of the tests get executed I'm looking for an easy way of telling eclipse "Run all TestNG test of package foo".

I can set-up a run configuration and explicitely list all packages with test classes. But this is not really handy if you have a lot of packages. If I list the base package only, no tests are excecuted.

How can I tell eclipse to run all test in all sub packages without listing them explicitely?

Comment: Is it not possible to write an xml file ..? you can group all the test cases in groups and multiple groups into suites  as you develop the test cases .. 


If order of executing test cases is of less importance, then you could just right click on the parent folder and run as testng suite will run your test cases.


May be with some effort, if you can templatize your classes using some template engine like Apache Velocity, you can also generate the xml file without typing them explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the package with the tests (not the main code *being tested*) and select "Run as...", then "unit test"

Afaik it runs all sub-packages too.

Comment: All options in the "Run as ..." popup are grayed out if I try this on a package.